# Facebook AppLinks on fresh installs

Tags: ios, facebook, applinks

According to this documentation (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks/ios), if the app is not installed on the device, the user will see an option to install it.  I could see that Facebook has used SKStoreProductViewController to accomplish this.

If the user installs the app, it seems like the app should open on its own after the download with the correct al_applink_data, but I never see this happening.  The app never opens on its own; it's up to the user to open the app on his own.

As far as know "application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:" won't be called until the device registers the custom URL on its first launch.  If the app never opened after the install then this call can never happen.  If this is supposed to be working, then how?

Can anyone fill in the blanks?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and I'm still digging it.

However, let me point out that the custom URL on iOS is registered during the installation and not during the first app run. You can do the following experiment:

1. Install a fresh app with custom URL support
2. Do not run the app (just install it)
3. Open a custom URL supported by the app > **the app will open**